# worksheet change function with condition

Tags: vba, function, worksheet

I am trying to write a code to enter sales data by representatives by date in such a way that they can enter data in a row which has today's date in `Column A` and all other rows are locked. Also, once they enter the data in any cell of that row, the cell gets locked.

Please see my code for the same below. I am getting a runtime error in this. I am keeping all the cells in unlocked status in cell formatting and have locked the worksheet before execution of this code.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

i = Target.Row  
If Range("A" & i) = Date Then

ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="jayant1234"
Target.Locked = True
ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="jayant1234"

Else
Target.Value = ""
MsgBox ("Don't Try To Mess Around")
End
End If
End Sub
```

`

Comment: Definitely set `Application.EnableEvents = False` before doing `Target.Value = ""` (and set it back to `True` afterwards) or else you are going to get yourself into an infinite loop which will crash Excel.

Comment: It would help to know what the runtime error is and on which line.

Comment: probably better to lock all cells on workbook close, and unlock today's cells on workbook open in case VBA is not enabled. Even better use Access Forms for data entry http://holowczak.com/advanced-access-forms-design-access/

Comment: @YowE3K: I add those 2 lines to the code and it helped to avoid infinite loop.

Answer (score -1):

Consider passing Target parameter as a String instead of Range.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As String)

i = Range(Target).Row
If Range("A" & i) = Date Then

    ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="jayant1234"
    Range(Target).Locked = True
    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="jayant1234"

Else
    Range(Target).Value = ""
    MsgBox ("Don't Try To Mess Around")
    End
End If
End Sub

Sub Test()

Worksheet_Change ("A1")

End Sub
```

Comment: By leaving it as `Range` you can simply do `Target.Row` i.e. `If Range("A" & Target.Row) = Date`. That's the more succinct way in my view.

Comment: This code is giving an error "Procedure declaration does not match description of event or Procedure having same name"

Comment: You cannot just change the procedure declaration of events - the `Worksheet_Change` event is passed a `Range` object, so the declaration has to be `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)`.